# new to android - can you explain what is a 4-byte memory boundary

Tags: java, android, c++

Android runs on  4-byte memory boundary. I tried to look through some documentation, but could not find anything. The problem is that it is important to know

Comment: More importantly, **why** is it important to know?

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that the Android system uses 32-bit (4-byte) memory alignment for variables (e.g., an `int` will always be saved at a memory address such as 32, 36, or 40, never at 42).

Answer (score 1):

Android devices uses 32-bit processors, this means that they work most efficently with data aligned on 32 bits (4 bytes). In case of Android app development, what is important is that if your application contains uncompressed data (ex. images), then android can map this data straight into memory using mmap() call (this saves a lot of memory, otherwise system would have to make o copy of this data to make it aligned). So mmap makes your apk look like memory, but for this to work your data must be correctly aligned on 4-byte memory boundary. To achive that you use zipalign tool, ex:

```
$ zipalign -v 4 notaligned_app.apk aligned_app.apk
```

also it is important to align after signing. Google Play should actully reject your apk if it was not zipaligned.

Comment: From the Google Android zipalign docs :

1. If you use apksigner , zipalign must only be performed before the APK file has been signed. If you sign your APK using apksigner and make further changes to the APK, its signature is invalidated.
2. If you use jarsigner , zipalign must only be performed after the APK file has been signed.

(https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign)